# Powerapps Survey to Sharepoint List

Tags: list, survey, powerapp

I want to make a Powerapp survey which creates an element in a Sharepoint list with the answers.

I started off With the survey template in Powerapp. However, I am not sure how to collect the data and save them to a New element in my Sharepoint list.

How can I go about doing that?

### Update

I am looking for the syntax With which I can collect data and save that data to a New element in my Sharepoint list. I am not looking for a template which will do everything for me.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, When you choose PowerApps template you can either save in `Common Data Services` or `One drive for business` there is an option right below the Template list called `change`. However, there you find options(Connectors) `Cloud drives` to store your data.

So straight answer is if you use the predefined template and it does not show SharePoint connector in `change` then you can only use those templates from the pre-defined connectors.

**Use SharePoint**

There are 2 things you can do:

1. Develop things from blank and use SharePoint as your source
2. Convert the template to use SharePoint(you are still doing above step except for UI design).

> **Reference**: refer these articles as needed [Step by step series](http://ratsubsharewall.blogspot.in/2017/03/develop-powerapps-from-scratch-series1.html), [here](https://collab365.community/powerapps-tutorial/)

---

**UPDATE**

Go to "Insert->New Form" [Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/functions/function-form) to create View/Edit scenarios. but if you have a proper reason not to use then use the below methods.

You can use [COLLECT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/functions/function-clear-collect-clearcollect) function to create a new item/record and [PATCH](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/functions/function-patch) or [UPDATE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/functions/function-update-updateif) method to modify existing values in an item specific column value or 
 entire record.

Comment: That is more or less the answer I was looking for, but I won't accept since the documentation is actually outdated (the syntax is wrong). Even with correct syntax, I cannot make it work; the collect function creates a New list element, but does not fill the columns with values (my function is Collect('Test List PowerApps';{Title:Radio1.Selected.Value;Column:Slider1.Value;Tekst:TextInput1.Text});;Navigate(Finish_Screen; ScreenTransition.Fade;{ans5:TextInput1.Text}))

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger Microsoft Flow to submit the collected information to SharePoint. Please refer to the instructions [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/using-logic-flows)

Mentioned below are the steps at high level.

- Create a Flow and select trigger action as a powerapp and save the flow.
- please note that, we cannot select powerapp from flow, hence the flow need to be triggered from the powerapp.
- The challenge is that the powerapp supplies just one parameter to the flow as a plain text, you need to ensure to append all the responses to this parameter
- Now, again in the MS Flow, Use the formula(expression), extract the responses and then add extracted text to the corresponding list items in the SharePoint using the *create item* SharePoint action.

Hope this is information is helpful.